# EM radiation hitting atoms

Tags: electromagnetic, wave

What happens when the EM wave is incident on a atom?
Do the de-localized electrons in the atoms or the valence band electons move in the direction of the electric field?
Also when the electrons move, does the magnetic field in the EM wave also exert a force on the moving electrons?

[image]

Comment: This question has now been reposted on Physics.SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685630) (rather than being migrated) and since duplicating identical questions on different SE sites is generally [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068), it makes most sense to close down this question here, especially since the same answer has been added to the question over at Physics.SE as was written here,

Answer (score 4):

Remember the Schrödinger equation from which you know what a "delocalized electron" is?

$$ j\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t) = \left [ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x,t)\right ] \Psi(x,t) $$

Exactly in that you insert your time-dependent potential \$V(x,t)\$. You'll see that the derivative of the \$\Psi\$ now has a harmonic component.

> Do the de-localized electrons in the atoms … move

Um, we *really* need to be careful when we say that something without a location moves... but, yes, the probability mass \$\lvert\Psi(x,t)\rvert\$ is time-dependent under a changing potential at a fixed point \$x\$. So, the electrons' loci "move" (with spoken-out quotation marks).

> Also when the electrons move, does the magnetic field in the EM wave also exert a force on the moving electrons?

Err. Now I'm not sure how we can interpret "moving": The electron's probability of occurrence "move"; the electrons themselves "stochastically interact"; this is quantum regime, you can't first call something "delocalized" and in the next sentence act as if it was a classical (i.e., non-quantum) particle.

To me, this sounds like you're trying to apply Maxwell's equations to quantum things. Don't. Schrödinger's equation is what you'll need deal with.

Comment: Well okay, the electrons probability of occurence moves according to an applied electric potential. How does the magnetic field affect the probability of occurence?

Comment: I mean this question really should be in the Physics exchange, since i dout any electrical engineer would know the details

Comment: @ThreadBucks it was pretty much my "solid state electronics" lecture, 4th semester EE. Not that "exotic", honestly.

Comment: To incorporate your magnetic field explicitly (and I was assuming you were doing that), use the vector potential for \$V(x,t)\$. (the thing is probably called \$A(x,t)\$ in your derivation of Maxwell / potential fields.

Comment: @ThreadBucks but if you want to move this to the physics.SE, feel free! (they might be using slightly different notation than what you're used to, though). To do that, you click on "Flag" beneath your question, ask for Moderator Intervention and in the text field there say you'd like to migrate.